# Accessing user attributes in lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Given the user's cognito-Id is there a way to get the custom attributes associated with them in lambda?

The attribute I am referring to is timezone, since time is saved in unix in database, when it is converted for the user to see, I would need to know their timezone.

*Extra text as question did not meet quality standard*

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37963906/how-to-get-user-attributes-username-email-etc-using-cognito-identity-id

Answer (score 3):

If you're using API Gateway with Cognito authorizer (and Lambda proxy integration), you can get the user's custom attributes via `requestContext`, for example `event.requestContext.authorizer.claims["custom:timezone"]`.

(By the way, Cognito provides a standard attribute called `zoneinfo`.)

If you're not using Cognito authorizer, you can get the user's custom attributes using [AdminGetUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminGetUser.html) by providing the username and user pool ID. In this case, your Lambda function's IAM role needs to have an allow rule to execute the `"cognito-idp:AdminGetUser"` action against your user pool resource.