# What does the `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin` scope mean in Amazon Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

Amazon Cognito has a number of system-reserved scopes:

- openid
- email
- phone
- profile
- aws.cognito.signin.user.admin

But doesn't document what they give access to.

The first 3 are fairly self-explanatory. I would expect profile to mean the user profile.

I've found by trial-and-error that I need `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin` to use the Amazon Cognito [Get User API call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GetUser.html). I would have expected this to be `profile` instead, but OK, fine.

What I'm concerned about is what **else** `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin` might do. If I let 3rd party clients request this scope, what am I giving them access to?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin` scope gives you access to all the User Pool APIs that can be accessed using access tokens alone [(full documentation here)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-idp-settings.html).

Note that this doesn't mean that the user would have arbitrary access to all the AWS API (like an IAM role might), but that if the request syntax for that API call includes `"AccessToken": "string"`, then an access token granted using `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin` will be able to call it.

As a rule, the Cognito UserPools API's (and it's *only* Cognito UserPool APIs) that authorise like this are ones that allow you to modify something on your own UserPools profile (i.e. do not start with `Admin` and affect a single profile):

At a glance through the API, these actions are (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html):

- AssociateSoftwareToken
- ChangePassword
- ConfirmDevice
- DeleteUser
- DeleteUserAttributes
- ForgetDevice
- GetDevice
- GetUser
- GetUserAttributeVerificationCode
- GlobalSignOut
- ListDevices
- SetUserMFAPreference
- SetUserSettings
- UpdateDeviceStatus
- UpdateUserAttributes
- VerifySoftwareToken
- VerifyUserAttribute

Comment: Really helpful, thanks.

Just to note, your first link is broken.

Comment: No worries- are you sure about the broken links though- they both work fine for me?

Comment: The first link claims to be going to `cognito-user-pools-app-idp-settings.html`, but instead takes you to 'What is Amazon Cognito?'.

The second link is fine.

Comment: Ahh- I see- fixed. For future prosperity!

Comment: the GetUser actions is only available for `openid` scoped tokens, not the `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin`. That's actually a problem I'm having, cognito SDK's are getting tokens lacking an `openid` scope therefore the getUser call returns a 401

Comment: `userinfo` endpoint is not allowed. `openid` scope is needed

Comment: The docs have a list of "Token-authenticated user operations" here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pools-API-operations.html