# Cognito AssociateSoftwareToken: token does not have required scopes

Tags: amazon-cognito, multi-factor-authentication

I am setting up TOTP-based MFA in Cognito according to the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-mfa-totp.html). The user pool is configured, the next step is to associate the token. Using boto3:

```
client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
client.associate_software_token(access_token)
```

Which returns the error:

```
NotAuthorizedException when calling the AssociateSoftwareToken operation: 
Access Token does not have required scopes
```

The token has the scopes `email profile openid`. What am I missing, what other scopes does it expect?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are missing the `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin` scope that is required by pretty much all actions related to users account.

See this question for more details: [What does the `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin` scope mean in Amazon Cognito?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53149091/what-does-the-aws-cognito-signin-user-admin-scope-mean-in-amazon-cognito)

Answer (score 15):

Following up on the (correct) answer by @Aleksandar Wons above, here's a screenshot that shows how/where to set the aws.cognito.signin.user.admin scope in your Cognito app client.

[image]

Comment: I have a similar issue where it works from the AWS console, but when I call from my app it does not. It is the same code!  So odd.

Comment: If you're using Amplify, you need to add this scope to your frontend inside Amplify configuration