# AWS AppSync Console + Amazon Cognito User Pool: Access Token Instead of ID Token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync, aws-sdk-js

I noticed that when I login through a Cognito User Pool on the AWS AppSync Console and I run a query or mutation, the [ID Token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-id-token.html) is sent from the console to authenticate / identify me as a user. I want an [Access Token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-access-token.html) to be sent instead from the console. I need to do this because the logic behind the mutation I have calls on current user operations to modify the current user via the AWS SDK ([only an access token allows this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53149091/what-does-the-aws-cognito-signin-user-admin-scope-mean-in-amazon-cognito)). I was wondering if it's possible for the AWS AppSync console to send an Access Token instead of ID Token.