# AWS CLI: Get user details from Cognito Identities

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cli

Using the AWS CLI, how to get user details (username, e-mail) from Cognito Identities?

This question relates to https://stackoverflow.com/a/55436168/1692112, which no longer seems to be working in 2021.
The problem is, the `sub` attribute in the User Pool no longer matches the `IdentityId` in the Identity Pool.

List of users in the User Pool:

```
$ aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id XX-XXXXX-X_XXXXXXXXX

{
    "Users": [
        {
            "Username": "my.username.yay",
            "Attributes": [
                {
                    "Name": "sub",
                    "Value": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "email_verified",
                    "Value": "true"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "email",
                    "Value": "my.username.yay@my.company.yay"
                }
            ],
            "UserCreateDate": 1612361296.687,
            "UserLastModifiedDate": 1612361331.99,
            "Enabled": true,
            "UserStatus": "CONFIRMED"
        }
    ]
}
```

List of identities in the Identity Pool:

```
$ aws cognito-identity list-identities --identity-pool-id XX-XXXXXXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX --max-results 50

{
    "IdentityPoolId": "XX-XXXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Identities": [
        {
            "IdentityId": "XX-XXXXXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "Logins": [
                "cognito-idp.XX-XXXXXXX-X.amazonaws.com/XX-XXXXXXX-X_XXXXXXXXX"
            ],
            "CreationDate": 1612795279.758,
            "LastModifiedDate": 1612795279.771
        }
    ]
}
```

I had been sort of hoping that the list of `Logins` would somehow mention the username or `sub`, but it just references the whole User Pool.

Theoretically, it might be possible to use AWS Lambda and AWS Cognito Triggers to connect the two pools and store the IDs somewhere. However, I would assume that AWS Cognito already knows the connection between the two pools and that there's a simple command for the job.

Edit: It appears that even by the time the last Cognito trigger `Pre Token Generation` is invoked, the identity does not exist yet. Moreover, the `event` structure does not reference the identity anywhere. Thus, AWS Lambda and Cognito Triggers would not provide a workaround to the AWS CLI, either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `aws cognito-idp get-user`/`aws cognito-idp admin-get-user` should do the trick.

Comment: @Dunedan `aws cognito-idp get-user` expects an access token from the user, which I'm afraid the admin doesn't have. `aws cognito-idp admin-get-user` seems to produce the same output as `aws cognito-idp list-users` which I've listed above (lacks IdentityID), just filtered to a specific user.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't notice that you're looking for an association between an identity in an identity pool and a user in a user pool.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Kenneth No, but for my use case (access control of S3 objects, based on Cognito login), AWS recommended using just the User Pool with API Gateway or CloudFront. I have not tried yet if or how these would work out.